# What is the suitable solution for consulting engineering company SharePoint or custom web application?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

We are planning to establish a solution for our company and we have a huge IT dept with experts developers, some of them prefer to apply SharePoint and some of them prefer to develop an application (Solution) from the scratch using asp.net technology with sql server database,
Our main jobs; save data and track documents between sections (design & Supervisions), payroll system, website, inventory system & Filing system.
Please I need a recommendation from stackoverflow experts.
And what is the best solution for sustainability, low cost & best performance?

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion SharePoint will be a far better solution for what you describe. First of all, when you look at what you get out of the box, you'll see that developing all that functionality will cost you far more than buying SharePoint. You have an integrated platform where you can create assets with 2 mouse clicks. Stuff like sites, lists, libraries, web parts and pages.
You have a complete Active Directory services integration out of the box, where you sync your user profiles with AD with a few clicks.
You have a robust built in permissions engine. And that's just scratching the surface.

Comment: how the cost will be more than buying SharePoint? as I told you that I have developers team so thay can build any solution for free and nothing cost me regardless thier salaries, and another thing; Does SharePoint is suitable for payroll system & inventory System & Filing System?